# Faking register reads in C

Tags: c, macros, embedded, arm, cpu-registers

I have an existing code base for an embedded system with no operating system. I'm trying to get it to build with the x86 gcc instead of just the cross compiler, as a first step toward being able to unit test on the host. Unfortunately there are direct register reads and writes all over the place, instead of using the provided abstraction layer. One option of course is to fix that; replace the direct register access with calls to the GPIO access functions. I'm hoping to get up to speed faster by introducing a macro (used in the x86 build only) to redefine pieces of the code like

```
myvar = (GPIOC->IDR >> 6) & 0x03;   // Read bits 6 and 7
GPIOD->CRL &= 0xFFFFFF0F;
```

to something like:

```
myvar = (myGpiocIdrReadFunc() >> 6) & 0x03;   // Read bits 6 and 7
myGpiodClrWriteFunc() &= 0xFFFFFF0F;
```

GPIOx's are #defined as pointers to a physical address. Of course if I try to read and write directly to addresses on my PC with an executable built with x86, that would be access violation. Unfortunately if I try something like this:

```
#define GPIOC->IDR { myGpiocIdrReadFunc() }
```

the compiler doesn't like that "->", saying "missing whitespace after the macro name."

If you've solved this kind of problem before, how did you do it?

Comment: I assume the goal is not just to blindly allow I/O to "succeed", but to have side effect functions from such I/O? Otherwise, you could just use a struct (GPIOD) with a CRL element.

Comment: @Yann: I was going to post the same (re: structs) as an answer, I'll +1 your answer if you post one.

Comment: Agree with @Yann: are you going to simulate the hardware or just wanna ignore it? You know, usually it actually does something.

Comment: I want to be able to set "read" values and retrieve "write" values.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
typedef struct {
    int IDR;
    int CRL;
} gpio_t;

gpio_t c;
gpio_t d;

gpio_t * GPIOC = &c;
gpio_t * GPIOD = &d;
```

Just keep adding registers like `IDR` to the `struct` as the compiler screams at you.

**EDIT** I edited the answer after I saw your comment that you actually want to simulate the values, this way you can, but bear in mind that you need to initialized them like in your hardware.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you're after literally replacing that string in the source. Why don't you just do that with a non-interactive editor like `sed`? You probably have a build system which could, depending on the architecture, do the replacement or not.

Comment: Oh, of course... define my own abstraction functions which, when built for the target, do the actual reads and writes, and when built for x86, do what I want. I was hoping to avoid modifying the original source code since I do not yet have access to the target hardware to make sure I don't break anything, but with care this might be the right approach.

Answer (score 1):

In case the solution from hexa isn't quite sufficient, here is a second option, which allows you to actually simulate the behaviour of the registers being referred to (including side effects etc). As a downside, this requires C++ (and that your existing C code can be compiled as C++, which is often a difficult requirement), and that the structs don't use native types directly but some alias instead.

You could define a class that implements `operator=`, `operator int`, and any other access functions you might need (`&=` etc). If the fields in the struct `GPIOC` points to are of a type you can change, you can then simply change that type to refer to your register class.

Something roughly like this:

```
#ifdef USE_REAL_HW

typedef volatile uint32_t HW_REGISTER32;

#else // (USE_REAL_HW not defined)

template<class T>
class RegisterAbstractionClass {
public:
    const T operator= (const T value) {
        data = value;
        return value;
    };
    operator const T() {
        return data;
    };
    // Other operators...
protected:
    volatile T data;
};

typedef RegisterAbstractionClass<uint32_t> HW_REGISTER32;

#endif // (USE_REAL_HW)

typedef struct {
    HW_REGISTER32 IDR;
    HW_REGISTER32 CRL;
} gpio_t;
```

(Note that the above is somewhat simplified: both `IDR` and `CRL` would behave identically in this case, which is probably not the case with the hardware.)

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have your #define the wrong way round. Try "#define MyGpiocIdrReadFunc() x86ReadFunc()" for the macro on your test system. Of course you'll need to replace all the reads from GPIOC->IDR with MyGpiocIdrReadFunc(). You'll also need to implement that function. Which is probably about as much work as fixing the code to use the abstraction layer you mentioned.

Answer (score -1):

I don't think it will be easy.

Note that the SFRs are usually `volatile`, and many arithmetic operations are atomic. So, the code

```
GPIOD->CRL &= 0xFFFFFF0F;
```

won't be equivalent to

```
setter(CLR_reg, getter(CLR_reg) & 0xFFFFFF0F);
```

Also note that there could be a busy waiting loop for an interrupt, and even interrupt handlers.

Comment: that helps nothing. he is trying to fake it.

Comment: You're quite right. Maybe I could replace all direct register access with my own abstraction functions, and then for the cross build #define those function calls back into the direct access... ugh.